# django-celery managment command giving AttributeError: '_multiprocessing.SemLock' object has no attribute 'name'

Tags: python, django, django-celery, kombu

I want to send an notification email to admin e.g if post is spamed then admin should get email.
am using django-celery templated_email and kombu.
but when i run the any management command of djcelery am getting error

D:\test\testapp>python manage.py celeryd -l info
     C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django_celery-3.0.4-py2.7.egg\djcelery\loaders.py:116:
      UserWarning: Using settings.DEBUG leads to a memory leak, n
      warnings.warn("Using settings.DEBUG leads to a memory leak, never "

```
 -------------- celery@Siddhatech_A-PC v3.0.4 (Chiastic Slide)
  ---- **** -----
 --- * ***  * -- [Configuration]
 -- * - **** --- . broker:      djkombu.transport.DatabaseTransport://localhost//
 - ** ---------- . app:         default:0x28c3390 (djcelery.loaders.DjangoLoader)
 - ** ---------- . concurrency: 4 (processes)
 - ** ---------- . events:      OFF (enable -E to monitor this worker)
 - ** ----------
 - *** --- * --- [Queues]
 -- ******* ---- . celery:      exchange:celery(direct) binding:celery
 --- ***** ----- . email:       exchange:celery(direct) binding:email

  [Tasks]
    . djcelery_email_send
    . testapp.tasks.add

Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\billiard-2.7.3.10-py2.7-billiard\forking.py", line 496, in main
     self = load(from_parent)
    File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 1378, in load
    return Unpickler(file).load()
    File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 858, in load
   [2012-10-04 14:45:25,960: ERROR/MainProcess]Unrecoverable error:AttributeError("'_multiprocessing.SemLock' object has no attribute 'name'",)
   Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\celery-3.0.4-py2.7.egg\celery\worker\__init__.py", line 348, in start
   component.start()
   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\celery-3.0.4-py2.7.egg\celery\concurrency\base.py", line 109, in start
   self.on_start()
   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\celery-3.0.4-py2.7.egg\celery\concurrency\processes\__init__.py", line 84, in on_start
   **self.options)
   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\billiard-2.7.3.10-py2.7-win32.egg\billiard\pool.py", line 799, in __init__
   self._create_worker_process()
   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\billiard-2.7.3.10-py2.7-win32.egg\billiard\pool.py", line 867, in _create_worker_process
   w.start()
   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\billiard-2.7.3.10-py2.7-win32.egg\billiard\process.py", line 138, in start
   self._popen = Popen(self)
   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\billiard-2.7.3.10-py2.7-win32.egg\billiard\forking.py", line 350, in __init__
   dump(process_obj, to_child, HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\billiard-2.7.3.10-py2.7-win32.egg\billiard\forking.py", line 143, in dump
   ForkingPickler(file, protocol).dump(obj)
   File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 224, in dump
   self.save(obj)
   File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 331, in save
   self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
   File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 419, in save_reduce
   save(state)
   File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 286, in savef(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
   File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 649, in save_dict
   self._batch_setitems(obj.iteritems())
   File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 681, in _batch_setitems
   save(v)
   File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 286, in save
   f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
   File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 562, in save_tuple
   save(element)
   File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 331, in save
   self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
   File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 419, in save_reduce
   save(state)
   File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 286, in save if(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
   File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 562, in save_tuple
   save(element)
   File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 306, in save
    rv = reduce(self.proto)
   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\billiard-2.7.3.10-py2.7-win32.egg\billiard\synchronize.py", line 122, in __getstate__
   sl.name)
   AttributeError: '_multiprocessing.SemLock' object has no attribute 'name'
   dispatch[key](self)
   File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 880, in load_eof
   raise EOFError
   EOFError
   [2012-10-04 14:45:26,299: INFO/MainProcess] process shutting down
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Please upgrade to celery 3.0.11 and specifically the latest billiard version as this Windows specific bug was fixed recently